# How to use Java Mongodb's AggregateToCollectionOperation class?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have this mongo shell command that I need to convert to Java code.
Looks like the driver API changes so often that any examples I see online don't use this method. I am using latest 3.2.4 version of the driver.

```
db.ff1987_2gram.aggregate([ 
   { 
       $group: { 
           _id : { 
               "cw1" : "$cw1", 
               "target" : "$target"
           }, 
           "count" : {"$sum" : 1 }  
       }
  },
  {$out : "ff1987_2gram_c"} 
], { allowDiskUse:true} )
```

https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.2/com/mongodb/operation/AggregateToCollectionOperation.html has what I want to do. But its execute method takes a WriteBinding interface object. This is implemented by ClusterBinding, SingleServerBinding. But I am not using either of these. I have connected to database using the new MongoClient class.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not answer my original question, the following is a decent workaround. I guess this is a deprecated class now since MongoClient was introduced.

Instead of using the AggregateToCollectionOperation use a normal aggregation operation with one of the stages with $out, just as in the mongo shell command. However keep in mind that unless you iterate the iterable that is returned, the command doesn't actually get executed. (It might be enough to break after the first element. Will update after I check that). An example below.

```
List<Document> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();
...
Document group = new Document("$group", groupargs);
pipeline.add(group);
...
//Relevant line
pipeline.add(new Document("$out", collectionname));
AggregateIterable<Document> docs = db.getCollection(collection).aggregate(pipeline).allowDiskUse(true);
for (Document d : docs) {}
```